# Disable rendering of subcategory text after navigating to that subcategory - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

StackOverflow community. I would like to ask for your help.

My problem is that I want to display all subcategories text in the main category card-box.
Using this code,

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID', 30);

function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($category)
{
    $parent_category_ID = $category->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0, // Set to 0 to show empty categories and 1 to hide them
        'parent' => $parent_category_ID,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories($args);
    echo '<div class="custom_subcategory_main">';
    echo '<span class="custom_subcategory_klasy">Dostępne klasy:</span><br>';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo '<span> '.$subcategory->name.'</span>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<span class="custom_subcategory_klasy">Poziom:</span><br>';
    echo '<span>Szkoła podstawowa</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

the subcategories text is displaying correctly in the main category card-box [screen below].
[image: correct rendering of the subcategory text]

The problem is that after navigating to the product subcategory it is still visible and I would like to hide it. More precisely, I would like to hide this part of the code [screen below].

```
echo '<span class="custom_subcategory_klasy">Dostępne klasy:</span><br>';
```

[image: I would like to hide what is highlighted in red]

Comment: If you are just getting that header, but no output below it, that must mean `$subcategories` did not contain any items, so the foreach loop didn't iterate at all. So wrap the whole thing into a condition that checks if that array is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand properly, once you're in a subcategory, there are no further children. So you could put a check inside your function to see if children exists, and if not, exit:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID', 30);

function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($category)
{
    $parent_category_ID = $category->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0, // Set to 0 to show empty categories and 1 to hide them
        'parent' => $parent_category_ID,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories( $args );
    if ( empty ( $subcategories ) ) return; // exit
    echo '<div class="custom_subcategory_main">';
    echo '<span class="custom_subcategory_klasy">Dostępne klasy:</span><br>';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo '<span> '.$subcategory->name.'</span>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<span class="custom_subcategory_klasy">Poziom:</span><br>';
    echo '<span>Szkoła podstawowa</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. In fact, your code does exactly what I need. Thank you for your help.